# Populate Datatable from 2 different sources using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to populate https://datatables.net/ from 2 different api endpoints from jQuery.

First endpoint (Owner  Api) retrieves only "Driver name",
the second endpoint (VehicleDetail Api) retrieves "Vehicle Name and Number Plate"

The database on the server is as follow, and it's a 1 to many relationship (1 owner may have multiple vehicles)

**1. TableOwner :**

```
  Fields
  -----------
  Id 
  Name
```

**2. TableVehicleDetail :**

```
  Fields
  -----------
  Id
  Name
  NumberPlate
  OwnerId       (Foreign Key)
```

My datatable has 3 columns (Driver Name, VehicleName, Number Plate), and I need to populate it from the two api endpoints.

**Driver Name** data must come from endpoint api called Owner,

**VehicleName**, **Number Plate** must come from endpoint api called VehicleDetail

I read that Datatable has a property called 'ajax source', I tried it but I couldn't achieve.

Regarding jQuery API, I'm using jquery Fetch API to retrieve data from endpoints api.

Below is the code I use. I have two similar code on the same page for both endpoints (Owner and VehicleDetail api).

```
// ******** Owner Start

        getData();

        async function getData() {
            const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44389/api/owners');
            const settings = {
                method: 'get',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
            const owner = await response.json();

            var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, owner));       // convert array to string
            var stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);                 // convert string to json object

            return stringToJsonObject;
        }

        getData().then(owner => {
            owner;

            $.each(owner, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value.name);                // Here data can be displayed on console.log
            });

        });

// ******** Owner End
```

// ******** VehicleDetail Start

```
    getData();

    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44389/api/vehicleDetail');
        const settings = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        const vehicle = await response.json();

        var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, vehicle));       // convert array to string
        var stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);                 // convert string to json object

        return stringToJsonObject;
    }

    getData().then(vehicle => {
        vehicle;

        $.each(vehicle, function (index, value) {
            console.log(value.name);                // Here data can be displayed on console.log
        });

    });
```

// ******** VehicleDetail End

Comment: You'll need to merge the data before sending it to DataTables, probably. Have you tried that?

Comment: you have not provided any detail how you have consumed the vehicle API?

Comment: it's the same as you see for owner api. Just added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON from the two different data sources looks like the following:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "driverName": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "driverName": "Mary"
  }
]
```

and:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "vehicleName": "Ford",
    "ownerId": "123",
    "numberPlate": "ABC 555"
  },
  {
    "id": "2345",
    "vehicleName": "Citroen",
    "ownerId": "123",
    "numberPlate": "DEF 678"
  },
  {
    "id": "3456",
    "vehicleName": "Toyota",
    "ownerId": "456",
    "numberPlate": "GHK 987"
  }
]
```

Then you can merge them by adding the owner name to each vehicle record - so, something like this:

```js
function fetchUrl(url) { 
  return $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    type: 'GET'
  } );
};

function merge(owners, vehicles) {
  // create a map, for owner ID to owner name lookups:
  let ownerMap = new Map();
  owners.forEach( (owner) => { 
    ownerMap.set(owner.id, owner.driverName);
  } )

  // add owner name to vehicle record:
  vehicles.forEach( (vehicle) => { 
    vehicle['driverName'] = ownerMap.get(vehicle['ownerId']);
  } )

  return vehicles;  
}
```

This is a very basic approach and does not try to account for cases where there may be an owner with no vehicle, a vehicle with no owner, one vehicle with multiple owners, and so on (so, no data quality checks).

---

Looking at the end-to-end approach:

Fetching the separate data sets:

```js
async function getTableData() {

  var ownersUrls = '[your URL here]';
  var vehiclesUrl = '[your URL here]';

  try {
    let owners = await fetchUrl(ownersUrls);
    let vehicles = await fetchUrl(vehiclesUrl);
    let dataSet = merge(owners, vehicles);
    initializeTable(dataSet);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

}

function fetchUrl(url) { 
  return $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    type: 'GET'
  } );
};
```

To pass the data to DataTables, I would add this at the start of the script:

```js
getTableData();
```

And finally, the table itself:

```js
function initializeTable(dataSet) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: dataSet,
      columns: [
        { title: 'Driver Name', data: 'driverName' },
        { title: 'Vehicle Name',  data: 'vehicleName' },
        { title: 'Number Plate', data: 'numberPlate' }
      ]
    } );
  } );
}
```

---

**Update**

Adjusting for the comments in the answer, we can handle both sources containing a `name` field by renaming the owner `name` field when we merge owners into vehicle records.

My updated JSON structures, which now use `name` in both data sets:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Mary"
  }
]
```

and:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "Ford",
    "ownerId": "123",
    "numberPlate": "ABC 555"
  },
  {
    "id": "2345",
    "name": "Citroen",
    "ownerId": "123",
    "numberPlate": "DEF 678"
  },
  {
    "id": "3456",
    "name": "Toyota",
    "ownerId": "456",
    "numberPlate": "GHK 987"
  }
]
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%"></table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

getTableData();

function initializeTable(dataSet) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: dataSet,
      columns: [
        { title: 'Driver Name', data: 'driverName' },
        { title: 'Vehicle Name',  data: 'name' },
        { title: 'Number Plate', data: 'numberPlate' }
      ]
    } );
  } );
}

async function getTableData() {

  var ownersUrls = 'your URL goes here';
  var vehiclesUrl = 'your URL goes here';

  try {
    let owners = await fetchUrl(ownersUrls);
    let vehicles = await fetchUrl(vehiclesUrl);
    let dataSet = merge(owners, vehicles);
    initializeTable(dataSet);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

}

function fetchUrl(url) { 
  return $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    type: 'GET'
  } );
};

function merge(owners, vehicles) {

  // create a map for owner ID to owner name:
  let ownerMap = new Map();
  owners.forEach( (owner) => { 
    ownerMap.set(owner.id, owner.name);
  } )

  // add owner name to vehicle record:
  vehicles.forEach( (vehicle) => { 
    vehicle['driverName'] = ownerMap.get(vehicle['ownerId']);
  } )

  return vehicles;  
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The `name` issue is handled by simply creating a field called `driverName` here:

```
vehicle['driverName'] = ...
```

and placing the owner's name into that field.

The DataTable refers to the field name we created:

```
{ title: 'Driver Name', data: 'driverName' }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  Indeed I'm getting error saying **javascript reference error: merge is not defined at getTableData**.  I tried to declare `let dataSet` as global variable but still getting the same error.     I'm using jquery-3.5.1.js

Comment: I updated to the latest jquery 3.6.0 **https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js**  but still getting the same error.

Comment: I tried to use merge with no data and I also tried with this small code taken [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for test purpose but still getting the same error. let obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
        `let obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };

        let mergedObj1 = merge(obj1, obj2);

        console.log(mergedObj1);`

Comment: I used `Object.assign` and it has worked. but I still have a small issue. The real api endpoint / database table both has one property called "name", so **merge** function cannot have same property name into one object. I updated the OP.

Comment: I provided an **Update** section at the end of my answer - and I showed the overall code, so you can see how all the different sections fit together.

Comment: It's almost working fine, only one issue. On the Datatable, DriverName column displaying the last value only from the table in every single row. it's not displaying all the value that is in the table.

Comment: I don't know what the latest version of your code looks like, or what source data you are using, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir. It solved my problem.